Exception when pressing up or down arrow keys inside a textFormField
In a simple form like a login form  with two TextFormFields for userName and password, when focus is inside the first field, when I press arrow down, I get these exceptions in the console:
======== Exception caught by services library ======================================================
The following assertion was thrown while processing the key message handler:
'package:flutter/src/rendering/editable.dart': Failed assertion: line 198 pos 12: 'isValid': is not true.


Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=2_bug.yml

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#2      VerticalCaretMovementRun.moveNext (package:flutter/src/rendering/editable.dart:198:12)
#3      _UpdateTextSelectionVerticallyAction.invoke (package:flutter/src/widgets/editable_text.dart:5665:37)
#4      _OverridableContextAction.invokeDefaultAction (package:flutter/src/widgets/actions.dart:1814:28)
#5      _OverridableActionMixin.invoke (package:flutter/src/widgets/actions.dart:1679:9)
#6      Action._invoke (package:flutter/src/widgets/actions.dart:336:19)
#7      ActionDispatcher.invokeActionIfEnabled (package:flutter/src/widgets/actions.dart:666:28)
#8      ShortcutManager.handleKeypress (package:flutter/src/widgets/shortcuts.dart:874:83)
#9      _ShortcutsState._handleOnKeyEvent (package:flutter/src/widgets/shortcuts.dart:1065:20)
#10     _HighlightModeManager.handleKeyMessage (package:flutter/src/widgets/focus_manager.dart:2002:39)
#11     KeyEventManager._dispatchKeyMessage (package:flutter/src/services/hardware_keyboard.dart:1103:34)
#12     KeyEventManager.handleRawKeyMessage (package:flutter/src/services/hardware_keyboard.dart:1175:17)
#13     BasicMessageChannel.setMessageHandler.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:235:49)
#14     _DefaultBinaryMessenger.setMessageHandler.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/services/binding.dart:603:35)
#15     _invoke2 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:344:13)
#16     _ChannelCallbackRecord.invoke (dart:ui/channel_buffers.dart:45:5)
#17     _Channel.push (dart:ui/channel_buffers.dart:135:31)
#18     ChannelBuffers.push (dart:ui/channel_buffers.dart:343:17)
#19     PlatformDispatcher._dispatchPlatformMessage (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:737:22)
#20     _dispatchPlatformMessage (dart:ui/hooks.dart:257:31)
(elided 2 frames from class _AssertionError)
KeyMessage: KeyMessage([KeyDownEvent#fa910(physicalKey: PhysicalKeyboardKey#556a0(usbHidUsage: "0x00070051", debugName: "Arrow Down"), logicalKey: LogicalKeyboardKey#80d00(keyId: "0x100000301", keyLabel: "Arrow Down", debugName: "Arrow Down"), character: null, timeStamp: 0:03:57.655037)])
====================================================================================================

I expect that when I press arrow down, the focus get moved to the next TextFormField, but it prints exceptions. I can move between fields by pressing Tab or Enter but it's not working with Up or Down arrow keys. Is there any solution for arrowKeys?
TextFormField(
              key: const Key('loginForm_usernameInput_textField'),
              textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
            )

